# Can't locate SBS 2011 Certification Authority Web interface

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, certificate-authority, windows-sbs-2011

Certification Authority    Installed
Certification Authority Web Enrollment Installed
Certification Enrollment Web Services Not Installed
Certification Enrollment policy web service Not Installed

This is under role services: I can't access

'http://$erverName/certserv'

What Is missing? any clue

Comment: Was able to fix this issue by re-installing just the cerfification authority web enrollment portion and was able to access http://localhost/certsrv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling Certification authority web Enrollment problem was fixed and now accissible via localhost --> certsrv